# Prevent UITableViewCell's textLabel frame from changing for device rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, device-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have a simple `UITableViewController` subclass with a few `UITableViewCell`s. I'm using the imageView and textLabel on each cell.

When I rotate the device to/from portrait/landscape the frame of the textLabel changes. The change is fine for portrait to landscape rotation. However when rotating back to portrait from landscape the frame changes to an "incorrect" value (text is justified inappropriately).

**How can I solve this?**

I had a similar issue with the imageViews' frames changing. I solved this by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and setting the frame to the correct value in `layoutSubviews`. Here there is only one `CGRect` value that I need to remember (and I just hardcode it).

The textLabel is different: I'd need to keep track of two frames (one for each orientation) and I think the frame values would depend on the textLabel's text. So adding two `CGRect` instance variables to my `UITableViewCell` subclass is an option. However I imagine there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Setting `numberOfLines` to three solved the problem.

I also had to set `self.textLabel.frame.origin.x` to a hardcoded value in layoutSubviews.

Not sure if I completely understand what's happeing here.